# Working with "unclean" text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please forgive my ignorance I am new at this. I have searched for this and tried several of the examples, but I think I am finding most things that might work in python2.7 but I am required to use python3.5 for work. I am trying to extract just the cities from this list on Wikipedia

[Cities in Oklahoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_and_cities_in_Oklahoma_by_population)

The tag names are different or I would try and use requests, which is actually ideal because we need to keep our list updated as Wikipedia updates. Instead I copied the data and pasted it into a txt document so that I can build the proof of concept and get approval for this project. I end up with something that looks like this:

```
1. Oklahoma City 1,012,389

2. Tulsa 609,450

3. Norman 110,925

4. Broken Arrow 98,850

5. Lawton (town) 96,867

6. Edmond 81,405

7. Moore 55,081

8. Midwest City 54,371
```

I have found several things that I have tried several different methods thinking that if I found the right way to split the file I could just get all lines that have content. Then I could split them again and return the line items with index 1.

I was trying:

```
file = open('cities_oklahoma.txt', 'r')
s = file.readline()

for line in s:
    line_has_txt = line.split() # I have no clue what should be here
    print([line_has_txt.split(' ')[1])
```

Am I even getting close to what I want to do here? Also please note I manipulated line 5 in my example to show some possible deviation of the data that happens. Also as you can see from line 1 some city names actually have the word city which kind of breaks my theory

Comment: It would probably make more sense to grab out the HTML content under the id `"Largest_10_cities_by_population"` and start parsing that

Comment: _"The tag names are different or I would try and use requests"_ - what does that mean? What are the tag names different than?

Comment: The census data is updated only every 10 years.

Comment: @BryanOakley I can now see that I was making a mistake. When looking at firebug it reorganized the tag names so that Oklahoma City had < a class=' as the first tag and every other city has <a herf=". I was thinking that made using Beautiful Soup a or requests a non-option.

Comment: @JustinR. Where can I find more up to date information?

Comment: @SpencerH this broadly falls in to the category of GIS data. Wikipedia has a good long list here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GIS_data_sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of Python libraries will make this pretty easy:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml.html import parse

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_and_cities_in_Oklahoma_by_population'
response = urlopen(url)
html = parse(response)
root = html.getroot()
span = root.get_element_by_id('Largest_10_cities_by_population')
h2 = span.getparent()

cities = []
current = h2
while current.tag != 'div':
    if current.tag == 'p' and current.find('a') is not None:
        cities.append(current.find('a').text)
    current = current.getnext()

print(cities)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: After working through all of them I think this answer best fits my needs. It is easy to understand and works! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the list of cities:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_and_cities_in_Oklahoma_by_population#Largest_10_cities_by_population")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

for p in soup.find("div",{"class":"mw-content-ltr"}).find_all("p"):
    print(p.text)
```

That gives you all the cities and the title:

```
The following list of towns and cities in Oklahoma, shows the incorporated places in the U.S. state of Oklahoma, in order of population according to the 2010 United States Census:[1]


1. Oklahoma City 1,012,389
2. Tulsa 609,450
3. Norman 110,925
4. Broken Arrow 98,850
5. Lawton 96,867
6. Edmond 81,405
7. Moore 55,081
8. Midwest City 54,371
9. Enid 49,379
10. Stillwater 45,688
11. Muskogee 39,223
12. Bartlesville 35,750
13. Shawnee 29,857
14. Owasso 28,915
.......................
359. Greenfield (town) 93
360. Roosevelt (town) 25
361. Cooperton (town) 12
```

You can skip the title and the empty strings, you have to be more careful what you filter but this is the general idea:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
ps = soup.find("div", {"class": "mw-content-ltr"}).find_all("p")

city_data = dict(p.text.lstrip("0123456789. ").rsplit(None, 1) for p in ps[3:])
from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(city_data)
```

Which gives you:

```
{'Achille town, Bryan County': '492',
 'Ada': '16,810',
 'Adair (town)': '790',
 'Afton (town)': '1,049',
 'Agra (town)': '339',
 'Alex (town)': '550',
 'Allen (town)': '932',
 'Altus': '19,813',
 'Alva': '4,945',
 'Amber town, Grady County': '419',
 'Anadarko': '6,762',
 'Antlers': '2,453',
 'Apache (town)': '1,444',
 'Arapaho (town)': '796',
 'Ardmore': '24,283',
 'Arkoma (town)': '1,989',
 'Arnett (town)': '524',
 'Asher town, Pottawatomie County': '393',
 'Atoka': '3,107',
 'Avant (town)': '320',
 'Barnsdall': '1,243',
 'Bartlesville': '35,750',
 'Beaver (town)': '1,515',
 'Beggs': '1,321',
 'Bernice (town)': '562',
 'Bethany': '19,051',
 'Bethel Acres (town)': '2,895',
 'Billings (town)': '509',
 'Binger (town)': '672',
 'Bixby': '20,884',
 'Blackwell': '7,092',
 'Blair (town)': '818',
 'Blanchard': '7,670',
 'Boise City': '1,266',
 'Bokchito (town)': '632',
 'Bokoshe (town)': '512',
 'Boley (town)': '1,184',
 'Boswell (town)': '709',
 'Bowlegs town, Seminole County': '405',
 'Bray (town)': '1,209',
 'Bristow': '4,222',
 'Broken Arrow': '98,850',
 'Broken Bow': '4,120',
 'Buffalo (town)': '1,299',
 'Burns Flat (town)': '2,057',
 'Butler (town)': '287',
 'Byng (town)': '1,175',
 'Cache': '2,796',
 'Caddo (town)': '997',
 'Calera (town)': '2,164',
 'Calumet (town)': '507',
 'Canton (town)': '625',
 'Canute (town)': '541',
 'Carmen (town)': '355',
 'Carnegie (town)': '1,723',
 'Carney (town)': '647',
 'Cashion (town)': '802',
 'Catoosa': '7,151',
 'Cement (town)': '501',
 'Central High (town)': '1,199',
 'Chandler': '3,100',
 'Chattanooga town, Comanche County': '461',
 'Checotah': '3,335',
 'Chelsea (town)': '1,964',
 'Cherokee': '1,498',
 'Cheyenne (town)': '801',
 'Chickasha': '16,036',
 'Choctaw': '11,146',
 'Chouteau (town)': '2,097',
 'Claremore': '18,581',
 'Clayton (town)': '821',
 'Cleveland': '3,251',
 'Clinton': '9,033',
 'Coalgate': '1,967',
 'Colbert (town)': '1,140',
 'Colcord (town)': '815',
 'Cole (town)': '555',
 'Collinsville': '5,606',
 'Comanche': '1,663',
 'Commerce': '2,473',
 'Cooperton (town)': '12',
 'Copan (town)': '733',
 'Corn (town)': '503',
 'Covington (town)': '527',
 'Coweta': '9,943',
 'Coyle town, Logan County': '325',
 'Crescent': '1,411',
 'Crowder town, Pittsburg County': '430',
 'Cushing': '7,826',
 'Custer City (town)': '375',
 'Cyril (town)': '1,059',
 'Davenport (town)': '814',
 'Davidson (town)': '315',
 'Davis': '2,683',
 'Del City': '21,332',
 'Delaware town, Nowata County': '417',
 'Depew (town)': '476',
 'Dewar (town)': '888',
 'Dewey': '3,432',
 'Dickson (town)': '1,207',
 'Dill City (town)': '562',
 'Dover town, Kingfisher County': '464',
 'Drummond (town)': '455',
 'Drumright': '2,907',
 'Duncan': '23,431',
 'Durant': '15,856',
 'Dustin town, Hughes County': '395',
 'Earlsboro (town)': '628',
 'East Duke (town)': '424',
 'Edmond': '81,405',
 'El Reno': '16,749',
 'Eldorado town, Jackson County': '446',
 'Elgin': '2,156',
 'Elk City': '11,693',
 'Elmore City (town)': '697',
 'Empire City (town)': '955',
 'Enid': '49,379',
 'Erick': '1,052',
 'Eufaula': '2,813',
 'Fairfax (town)': '1,380',
 'Fairland (town)': '1,057',
 'Fairview': '2,579',
 'Fanshawe (town)': '419',
 'Fletcher (town)': '1,177',
 'Forest Park (town)': '998',
 'Forgan (town)': '547',
 'Fort Cobb (town)': '634',
 'Fort Coffee town, Le Flore County': '424',
 'Fort Gibson (town)': '4,154',
 'Fort Supply (town)': '330',
 'Fort Towson (town)': '519',
 'Francis (town)': '315',
 'Frederick': '3,940',
 'Gage (town)': '442',
 'Garber': '822',
 'Geary': '1,280',
 'Geronimo (town)': '1,268',
 'Glencoe (town)': '601',
 'Glenpool': '10,808',
 'Goldsby (town)': '1,801',
 'Goodwell (town)': '1,293',
 'Gore (town)': '977',
 'Grandfield': '1,038',
 'Granite (town)': '2,065',
 'Greenfield (town)': '93',
 'Grove': '6,623',
 'Guthrie': '10,191',
 'Guymon': '11,442',
 'Haileyville': '813',
 'Hammon (town)': '568',
 'Harrah': '5,095',
 'Hartshorne': '2,125',
 'Haskell (town)': '2,007',
 'Haworth (town)': '297',
 'Healdton': '2,788',
 'Heavener': '3,414',
 'Helena (town)': '1,403',
 'Hennessey (town)': '2,131',
 'Henryetta': '5,927',
 'Hinton (town)': '3,196',
 'Hobart': '3,756',
 'Holdenville': '5,771',
 'Hollis': '2,060',
 'Hominy': '3,565',
 'Hooker': '1,918',
 'Howe (town)': '802',
 'Hugo': '5,301',
 'Hulbert (town)': '590',
 'Hydro (town)': '969',
 'Idabel': '7,010',
 'Indiahoma (town)': '344',
 'Inola (town)': '1,788',
 'Jay': '2,448',
 'Jenks': '16,924',
 'Jennings town, Pawnee County': '363',
 'Jones (town)': '2,692',
 'Kansas (town)': '802',
 'Kaw City city, Kay County': '375',
 'Kellyville (town)': '1,150',
 'Keota (town)': '564',
 'Ketchum Town, Craig County': '442',
 'Keyes (town)': '324',
 'Kiefer (town)': '1,685',
 'Kingfisher': '4,633',
 'Kingston (town)': '1,601',
 'Kiowa (town)': '731',
 'Konawa': '1,298',
 'Krebs': '2,053',
 'Lahoma (town)': '611',
 'Lamont town, Grant County': '417',
 'Langley (town)': '819',
 'Langston (town)': '1,724',
 'Laverne (town)': '1,344',
 'Lawton': '96,867',
 'Lexington': '2,152',
 'Lindsay': '2,840',
 'Locust Grove (town)': '1,423',
 'Lone Grove': '5,054',
 'Lone Wolf town, Kiowa County': '438',
 'Luther (town)': '1,221',
 'Madill': '3,770',
 'Mangum': '3,010',
 'Mannford (town)': '3,076',
 'Mannsville (town)': '863',
 'Marietta': '2,626',
 'Marlow': '4,662',
 'Maud': '1,048',
 'Maysville (town)': '1,232',
 'McAlester': '18,383',
 'McCurtain (town)': '516',
 'McLoud (town)': '4,044',
 'Medford': '996',
 'Medicine Park (town)': '382',
 'Meeker (town)': '1,144',
 'Miami': '13,570',
 'Midwest City': '54,371',
 'Mill Creek (town)': '319',
 'Millerton (town)': '320',
 'Minco': '1,632',
 'Moore': '55,081',
 'Mooreland (town)': '1,190',
 'Morris': '1,479',
 'Morrison (town)': '733',
 'Mounds (town)': '1,168',
 'Mountain Park town, Kiowa County': '409',
 'Mountain View (town)': '795',
 'Muldrow (town)': '3,466',
 'Muskogee': '39,223',
 'Mustang': '17,395',
 'New Cordell': '2,915',
 'Newcastle': '7,685',
 'Newkirk': '2,317',
 'Nichols Hills': '3,710',
 'Nicoma Park': '2,393',
 'Ninnekah (town)': '1,002',
 'Noble': '6,481',
 'Norman': '110,925',
 'North Enid (town)': '860',
 'North Miami town, Ottawa County': '374',
 'Nowata': '3,731',
 'Oakland town, Marshall County': '1,057',
 'Oaks (town)': '288',
 'Ochelata town, Washington County': '424',
 'Oilton': '1,013',
 'Okarche (town)': '1,215',
 'Okay (town)': '620',
 'Okeene (town)': '1,204',
 'Okemah': '3,223',
 'Oklahoma City': '1,012,389',
 'Okmulgee': '12,321',
 'Oktaha town, Muskogee County': '390',
 'Olustee (town)': '607',
 'Oologah (town)': '1,146',
 'Owasso': '28,915',
 'Paden (town)': '461',
 'Panama (town)': '1,413',
 'Paoli (town)': '610',
 'Pauls Valley': '6,187',
 'Pawhuska': '3,584',
 'Pawnee': '2,196',
 'Perkins': '2,831',
 'Perry': '5,126',
 'Piedmont': '5,720',
 'Pink (town)': '2,058',
 'Pocola (town)': '4,056',
 'Ponca City': '25,387',
 'Pond Creek': '856',
 'Porter (town)': '566',
 'Porum (town)': '727',
 'Poteau': '8,520',
 'Prague': '2,386',
 'Prue town, Osage County': '465',
 'Pryor': '9,539',
 'Purcell': '5,884',
 'Quapaw (town)': '906',
 'Quinton (town)': '1,051',
 'Ralston (town)': '330',
 'Ramona (town)': '535',
 'Randlett (town)': '438',
 'Ravia (town)': '528',
 'Red Oak (town)': '549',
 'Ringling (town)': '1,037',
 'Ringwood (town)': '497',
 'Ripley town, Payne County': '403',
 'Rock Island (town)': '646',
 'Roff (town)': '725',
 'Roland (town)': '3,169',
 'Roosevelt (town)': '25',
 'Rush Springs (town)': '1,231',
 'Ryan (town)': '816',
 'Salina (town)': '1,396',
 'Sallisaw': '8,880',
 'Sand Springs': '18,906',
 'Sapulpa': '20,544',
 'Savanna (town)': '686',
 'Sayre': '4,375',
 'Schulter (town)': '509',
 'Seiling': '860',
 'Seminole': '7,488',
 'Sentinel (town)': '901',
 'Shady Point (town)': '1,026',
 'Shattuck (town)': '1,356',
 'Shawnee': '29,857',
 'Shidler': '441',
 'Skiatook': '7,397',
 'Slaughterville (town)': '4,137',
 'Snyder': '1,394',
 'Soper (town)': '261',
 'South Coffeyville (town)': '785',
 'Spavinaw (town)': '437',
 'Spencer': '3,912',
 'Sperry (town)': '1,206',
 'Spiro (town)': '2,164',
 'Springer (town)': '700',
 'Sterling (town)': '793',
 'Stigler': '2,685',
 'Stillwater': '45,688',
 'Stilwell': '3,949',
 'Stonewall (town)': '470',
 'Stratford (town)': '1,525',
 'Stringtown town, Atoka County': '410',
 'Stroud': '2,690',
 'Sulphur': '4,929',
 'Taft (town)': '250',
 'Tahlequah': '15,753',
 'Talihina (town)': '1,114',
 'Taloga (town)': '299',
 'Tecumseh': '6,457',
 'Temple (town)': '1,002',
 'Terral town, Jefferson County': '382',
 'Texhoma (town)': '926',
 'Thackerville town, Love County': '445',
 'The Village': '8,929',
 'Thomas': '1,181',
 'Tipton (town)': '847',
 'Tishomingo': '3,034',
 'Tonkawa': '3,216',
 'Tryon town, Lincoln County': '491',
 'Tulsa': '609,450',
 'Tupelo': '329',
 'Tushka town, Atoka County': '312',
 'Tuttle': '6,019',
 'Tyrone (town)': '762',
 'Union City (town)': '1,645',
 'Valley Brook (town)': '765',
 'Valliant (town)': '754',
 'Velma (town)': '620',
 'Verden (town)': '530',
 'Verdigris (town)': '3,993',
 'Vian (town)': '1,466',
 'Vici (town)': '699',
 'Vinita': '5,743',
 'Wagoner': '8,323',
 'Wakita town, Grant County': '344',
 'Walters': '2,551',
 'Wanette town, Pottawatomie County': '350',
 'Wapanucka town, Johnston County': '438',
 'Warner (town)': '1,641',
 'Warr Acres': '10,043',
 'Washington (town)': '618',
 'Watonga': '5,111',
 'Waukomis (town)': '1,286',
 'Waurika': '2,064',
 'Wayne (town)': '688',
 'Waynoka': '927',
 'Weatherford': '10,833',
 'Webbers Falls (town)': '616',
 'Welch (town)': '619',
 'Weleetka (town)': '998',
 'Wellston (town)': '788',
 'West Siloam Springs (town)': '846',
 'Westville (town)': '1,639',
 'Wetumka': '1,282',
 'Wewoka': '3,430',
 'Wilburton': '2,843',
 'Wilson': '1,724',
 'Winchester (town)': '516',
 'Wister (town)': '1,102',
 'Woodward': '12,051',
 'Wright City (town)': '762',
 'Wyandotte (town)': '333',
 'Wynnewood': '2,212',
 'Wynona (town)': '437',
 'Yale': '1,227',
 'Yukon': '22,709'}
```

If you plan on analysing the data, you might find pandas useful::

```
city_data =(p.text.lstrip("0123456789. ").rsplit(None, 1) for p in ps[3:])
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(city_data,columns=["City", "Population"])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                  City Population
0                        Oklahoma City  1,012,389
1                                Tulsa    609,450
2                               Norman    110,925
3                         Broken Arrow     98,850
4                               Lawton     96,867
5                               Edmond     81,405
6                                Moore     55,081
7                         Midwest City     54,371
8                                 Enid     49,379
9                           Stillwater     45,688
10                            Muskogee     39,223
11                        Bartlesville     35,750
12                             Shawnee     29,857
13                              Owasso     28,915
14                          Ponca City     25,387
15                             Ardmore     24,283
16                              Duncan     23,431
17                               Yukon     22,709
18                            Del City     21,332
19                               Bixby     20,884
20                             Sapulpa     20,544
21                               Altus     19,813
22                             Bethany     19,051
23                        Sand Springs     18,906
24                           Claremore     18,581
25                           McAlester     18,383
26                             Mustang     17,395
27                               Jenks     16,924
28                                 Ada     16,810
29                             El Reno     16,749
..                                 ...        ...
```

You might want to convert the population column to ints for any calculations:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')

df["Population"] = df["Population"].apply(locale.atoi)
print(df["Population"])

0      1012389
1       609450
2       110925
3        98850
4        96867
5        81405
6        55081
7        54371
8        49379
9        45688
10       39223
11       35750
12       29857
..................
```

Comment: It's easier to iterate over the `p` tags and take the text of the contained `a` tag (if it exists). This ends up being pretty straight forward, even with `lxml.html` (see my answer).

Comment: It has taken me a few tries to get pandas installed, and get this to return what I want, but I like it.

Comment: It is just a quick intro, pandas is an extensive library with may great features, if you are going to be parsing scraped  html use a html parser like Beautifulsoup, don't use a regex unless it is a necessity.

Comment: The answer I chose got the job done but I am still trying this out on different pages with good success. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions will help you here.  [See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/kZ5mV1/1)

```
import re

file = open("cities_oklahoma.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    # Get rid of leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()
    m = re.match(r'^\d+\.\s+(?P<city>.+?)\s+(?P<population>\d+(?:,\d{3})*)$', line)
    if m:
        print m.group('city'), m.group('population')
```